# Electron - Cannot find module 'app' when building app

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

Im stuck at building electron app using angular.

Here are the logs

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
Require stack:
- /Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/main.js
- /Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:627:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:41:16)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/main.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
```

Here is my main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = require('app');
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')

let mainWindow

app.on('ready', _ => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 400,
    width: 400
  })
  mainWindow.on('closed', _ => {
    console.log('closed')
    mainWindow = null
  })
})
```

Starting node server by `node main.js`

And by `npm start` which is same `node main.js`

Tried reinstalling electron.

Moved electron from devdependencies to dependencies

Removed node_modules and then `npm install`

Then I changed to

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
```

Now, different bug

```
/Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/main.js:10
app.on('ready', _ => {
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saikrishna/Documents/Angular/popsql/main.js:10:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Is there anything I should try to get electron working

Answer (score 1):

It might be the result of not setting up the npm package. `npm init` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Electron is like cordova, this variables is only initialized when you are running electron, my advice?? Use this library https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron

And remember that electron can't works like ng serve, you must build the angular app and them run with a electron main js file. When electron app start, the electron global varibles will be init.